# Casting to (int *) of (&num) when num is float in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Why is the ouput of the following code : " i is: 1075838976"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int i = 2;
  float num = 2.5;

  i = *((int *)& num);
  printf("i is: %d\n", i);
}
```

Isn't it equivalent to :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int i = 2;
  float num = 2.5;

  i = num;
  printf("i is: %d\n", i);
}
```

Which outputs : "i is 2"?
Thanks.

Comment: No, it's (obviously) not equivalent. The one reinterprets the bit-pattern (invoking undefined behaviour on the way), the other does a value-conversion.

Comment: Highly related, possibly even a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3452439/319403

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's not equivalent at all.

This:

```
i = num;
```

converts the *value* of `num` (which is `2.5`) from `float` to `int`. The conversion truncates the value to `2`.

This:

```
i = *((int *)& num);
```

takes a pointer to the `float` object `num`, converts it to `int*`, and dereferences the resulting pointer.

If you're "lucky", this takes the bits making up the representation of `num`, *pretends* that they're the representation of an `int`, and gives you that results.

If you're not "lucky", then `int` and `float` may be of different sizes, a `float` object might be incorrectly aligned to be treated as an `int` object, or the result could even be a "trap representation" (though the latter is rare).

(I put "lucky" in quotation marks because, really, the *best* thing this code can do is blow up in your face, which immediately lets you know you're doing something questionable. The behavior is *undefined*, which means it's an error, but the implementation isn't required to warn you about it, either at compile time or at run time.)

The particular value you're getting, `1075838976`, can be represented in hexadecimal as `0x40200000`. If you look up the way `float` values are represented on your system, you can probably figure out how that bit pattern (`0100 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`) makes up the the sign, mantissa, and exponent values that represent the value `2.5`.

Answer (score 3):

In C "cast" is sort of "overloaded" and does two entirely different things:

-- Cause code to be generated to convert a "scalar" value between, say, `int` and `float`.

-- Coerce a *pointer* to a different type.  This does not actually generate any code and does not convert anything.

`((int *)& num)` is coercing a pointer from `float*` to `int*`, and does not do any data conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the machine to interpret the binary number explicitly as an int, without going through a cast.