# Given r^2, is there an efficient way to compute r^3?

Tags: c++, performance, floating-point, distance, square-root

```
double r2 = dx * dx + dy * dy;
double r3 = r2 * sqrt(r2);
```

Can the second line be replaced by something faster? Something that does not involve `sqrt`?

Comment: Your code seems to contradict your caption: Where in your code do you actually have r^2? You only have r2, which holds something very different than r squared... or I guess I misunderstood, "^" should not mean "to the power of"?

Comment: @nyarlathotep: Assume `r` is `sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)`.

Comment: @nyarlathotep you missed the point. If r = (dx*dx + dy*dy)^(1/2), than r2 = r^2. But that's not the issue.

Comment: I was just confused, ^ is the usual notation for "to the power of" as far as I know.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that, by the way the question is posed, technically the answer is NO.  The simple reason is that if you're given r^2, you don't know the sign of r, so how can you calculate r^3?  I think what you're really asking is, given the squared norm of a vector, can you find the cubed norm efficiently?

Comment: Depending on precision you need and dx/dy ratio, you can try Taylor series ( 1+x )^( 1/2 ) = 1 + ( 1/2 )*x - ( 1/8 )*x^2 + ... where x = ( dx/dy )^2 <= 1.

Comment: Depending on your desired precision, and the relative sizes of `dx` and `dy`, you could do a Taylor expansion: for example if you know `dy` is small compared to `dx`, then you can approximate `r3` as `dx(dx^2 + 3/2 * dy^2)` (I think I have that right).  EDIT: Wow, that's uncanny, AzzA!

Comment: How fast is `sqrt`, just so that people know what they're trying to beat? Does your compiler use SSE (or perhaps some equivalent on other achitectures)?

Comment: @SteveJessop: 3 answers so far, and not a single bench / disassembly. I don't think people are really interested in finding a faster answer, they just throw anything they can think of to the mob...

Comment: @Matthieu: I don't mind that so much - without knowing Fred's setup it's not possible to say what will be faster, and a benchmark on the answerer's setup proves nothing. I think it's fair to suggest things that plausibly might be faster so that he can test them, but if what we're trying to beat is `sqrtss` followed by `mul` then not much is plausible anyway. Part of the thrust of my question though is that the "fix" might just be to use a `-m` compiler option.

Comment: Oh, and of course the question would have made a lot more sense if the answer was "yes, of course there's a better way, your code is needlessly going around the houses, here's the simple thing you've missed". Complaints about "why aren't you profiling" would be absurd if Fred was Bogosorting 100 items and asking if anyone knew a better sort algorithm -- we don't need to profile to know that Bogosort is wrong. But since Fred's code is at or close to optimal, and the sqrt or something similar is unavoidable, it looks like a micro-optimization question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think another way to look at your question would be "*how to calculate (or approximate) sqrt(n)*". From there your question would be trivial (n * sqrt(n)). Of course, you'd have to define how much error you could live with. Wikipedia gives you many options:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Answer (score 14):

How about

```
double r3 = pow(r2,1.5);
```

If sqrt is implemented as a special case of pow, that will save you a multiplication.  Not much in the grand scheme of things mind!

If you are really looking for greater efficiency, consider whether you really need r^3.  If, for example, you are only testing it (or something derived from it) to see whether it exceeds a certain threshold, then test r2 instead e.g.

```
const double r3_threshold = 9;

//don't do this
if (r3 > r3_threshold)
    ....

//do do this
const double r2_threshold = pow(r3_threshold,2./3.); 
if (r2 > r2_threshold)
    ....
```

That way `pow` will be called only once, maybe even at compile time.

**EDIT** If you do need to recompute the threshold each time, I think the answer concerning Q_rsqrt is worth a look and probably deserves to outrank this one

Comment: What about `r2*r2*r2 > r3_thresh*r3_thresh`?

Comment: @dantswain Well that avoids `pow` but it takes extra multiplications and the code is less clear

Comment: Wouldn't a couple (three) extra mults be faster than pow?  I think readability is subjective here... I routinely do the squared case as `dx*dx + dy*dy < r_thresh*r_thresh`; the cubed version wouldn't throw me.  Besides, if readability was really an issue you could hide it in a macro or inline. *shrug*

Comment: Unless your math library is really crappy, sqrt() will not be implemented via pow(x, .5), and it will be a lot faster than pow() (IIRC I tested this at some point and with the libm in glibc sqrt() was about an order of magnitude faster). But yeah, I suppose it doesn't hurt trying it out..

Comment: @dantswain I think Sideshow Bob's point is about repeated checking against the same threshold, in which case a single pow would be better than many many muls (though it depends on the number of iterations). But of course for a one-time check your mul-version is better. I also think readability is of secondary concern, considering the micro-optimization nature of this problem.

Comment: @dantswain not if the `pow` is only computed at compile time, or once on program start up

Comment: Fair enough :)  In my case the thresh is usually changing between iterations and is set by the user, so I leave it in user-friendly units until the check.

Comment: @janneb  gcc -S -O tells me that some compilers (gcc 4.5.1 in my case) will actually optimize pow(r2,1.5) to r2 * sqrt(r2).

Answer (score 12):

Use [fast inverse sqrt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code) (take the `Q_rsqrt` function).

You have:

```
float r2;
// ... r2 gets a value
float invsqrt = Q_rsqrt(r2);
float r3 = r2*r2*invsqrt; // x*x/sqrt(x) = x*sqrt(x)
```

**NOTE:** For `double` types there is a constant like `0x5f3759df` which can help you write a function that handles also `double` data types.

**LATER EDIT:** Seems like the method has been already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349542/john-carmacks-unusual-fast-inverse-square-root-quake-iii).

**LATER EDIT2:** The constant for `double` was in the wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#History_and_investigation):

> Lomont pointed out that the "magic number" for 64 bit IEEE754 size
>   type double is 0x5fe6ec85e7de30da, but in fact it is close to
>   0x5fe6eb50c7aa19f9.

Comment: @SideshowBob Since it is used in Quake3 code I believe it to be the fastest

Comment: Times have changed since Quake 3 was written. For example SSE has a hardware sqrt instruction, which is faster.

Comment: [See here](http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/2009/10/16/timing-square-root/) for more information.

Comment: @IulianŞerbănoiu: it's nowhere near the fastest.  It is faster than the square root instruction on *some* platforms, but most mainstream CPUs can compute a more accurate reciprocal square root estimate in a single instruction requiring just a couple of cycles latency (`rsqrtss` on Intel, `frsqrte` on PPC, `vrsqrte` on ARM).

Comment: @SteveJessop I totally agree, but the OP didn't mention anything about HW instructions, which are clearly faster that these bit tricks. Unfortunately I don't know if the standard C library uses the SSE functions.

Comment: The question really reveals some very interesting facts.

Comment: The idea of `r^2*r^2/sqrt(r^2)` is still valid, whether you use the Quake trick or a hardware `1/sqrt` instruction.

Comment: @drhirsch: and that code has the especially desirable property of *irreducible unreadability*: the only way to make the code readable is to replace it with a completely different implementation, because the algorithm used is pretty much incomprehensible.

Comment: IMHO if you had to limit a processor to 4 FP math operations I'd pick + - * and reciprocal square root.