# How to move ST(0) to EAX?

Tags: assembly, x86, fpu, x87

Hullo, I am learning x86 FPU assembly, and I have
got a simple question I cannot find answer for:

How to move value from **`ST(0)`** ( top of the FPU 
stack ) to **`EAX`** ?

also:
is this code correct:

```
; multiply (dot) two vectors of 3 floats passed by pointers as arg 1 arg 2
; passings are ok I think, but not sure if multiplies-adds are ok

    push    ebp                                     
    mov     ebp, esp                                
    mov     eax, dword [ebp+8H]                     
    mov     edx, dword [ebp+0CH]                    

    fld     qword [eax]                             
    fmul    qword [edx]                             
    fld     qword [eax+4H]                          
    fmul    qword [edx+4H]                          
    fld     qword [eax+8H]                          
    fmul    qword [edx+8H]                          
    faddp   st1, st(0)                              
    faddp   st1, st(0)                            
    fstp    qword [ebp+10H]     ; here I vould prefer 'mov eax, st0'

    pop     ebp                                   
    ret
```

Comment: do you want the bit representation of the fp number in EAX or the integer representation(conversion)?

Comment: I think maybe I ve done some kind of mistake, I need to write c-like function that will return a float - I was mistaken by assumption that ret value is by eax but this is float so maybe i should just leave it on st0 -( now i realize so, ) besides are my FPU dot(float*, float*) calculations ok??

Comment: Yes, in the usual calling conventions, FP values are returned in `ST(0)`, or in `XMM0`.  Never in `eax`, because then the caller would have to bounce it back into `ST(0)` or `XMM0` to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real reason why you should. Remember that `EAX` is only a 32-bit register, while all the FPU registers are 80 bits in width, because the FPU does calculations on 80-bit floats by default. Therefore, moving data from the FPU register to a general purpose register will cause data loss. If you really want to do something like that, try this (assuming that you've got some stack space available) :

```
sub esp, 4           ; or use space you already reserved
fstp dword [esp]
mov eax, [esp]       ; or better,  pop eax
add esp, 4
```

This instruction sequence will round the float currently on the top of the FPU stack to a 32-bit one, then write it to a temporary stack location, load the `float` (binary32) bit pattern into `EAX`, and clean up the used stack space.

---

This is almost never what you want.  **The standard calling conventions return float / double / long double values in `st(0)`**, so that's where a C compiler will expect a `double foo()` function to leave the value.  (Or `xmm0` with SSE/SSE2).

You only need this if you want to do integer manipulation / tests on FP bit-patterns.  (i.e. to implement type-punning in C like `memcpy` from a `float` to `uint32_t`).  e.g. for the [famous but now mostly obsolete fast approximate inverse-`sqrtf` magic-number hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349542/john-carmacks-unusual-fast-inverse-square-root-quake-iii) used in Quake source code.

Comment: Ok, TNX for a way, Didnt know that there is no such instruction (it is a little sad maybe, to have to use ram as intermediate) But in such routine I ve tested i could leave result on top of stack - and it is ok

Comment: The last 2 instructions could be replaced with `pop eax`.  That would be at least as efficient on modern CPUs.  Of course normally you'd just reserve some stack space at the start of the function and store/reload to/from that instead of messing with the stack pointer inside a loop.

Answer (score 4):

There are no x87 instructions to move floating point values between the FPU registers and the CPU registers.

You have to use memory as the intermediate.

Comment: OK, Can you also state if my dot(float*, float*) procedure could be ok ?

Comment: Well, if you use doubles (qword = quad word = 4 * 2 bytes = 8 bytes), your offsets can't be 4. You should be able to test/debug your code easily.