# Is the Carmack/Welsh inverse square root algorithm biased

Tags: c, algorithm, math

When implementing ["Carmack's Inverse Square Root" algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349542/john-carmacks-unusual-fast-inverse-square-root-quake-iii) I noticed that the results seem biased. The following code seems to give better results:

```
float InvSqrtF(float x)
{
    // Initial approximation by Greg Walsh.
    int i  = * ( int* ) &x;
    i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );
    float y  = * ( float * ) &i;
    // Two iterations of Newton-Raphson's method to refine the initial estimate.
    x *= 0.5f;
    float f = 1.5F;
    y  = y * ( f - ( x * y * y ) );
    y  = y * ( f - ( x * y * y ) );
    * ( int * )(&y) += 0x13; // More magic.
    return y;
}
```

The key difference is in the penultimate "more magic" line. Since the initial results were too low by a fairly constant factor, this adds 19 * 2^(exponent(y)-bias) to the result with just a single instruction. It seems to give me about 3 extra bits, but am I overlooking something?

Comment: Exactly what is your question? "Is 19 the right number to add?" or something else?

Comment: Isn't this code doomed to undefined behaviour by the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The first part of algorithm dates back to the eighties, and there's been a lot of investigation in better magic constants for the first approximation. A lot of people have looked at it before. So I don't trust myself 100% here. Am I overlooking something that they saw? That's more likely than all of them overlooking this improvement.

Comment: Possibly that John Carmack didn't need three extra bits?

Comment: @comocomocomocomo: It already was at the first line; my addition works iff that works.

Comment: @BoPersson: He in fact didn't, since he even left the second Newton-Raphson's iteration commented out.

Comment: Is this actually faster than RSQRTSS (SSE reciprocal square root)?

Comment: @MSalters: Sorry, I didn't intend to critisize you nor the original coders. I am sincerely worried about the effects of the strict aliasing rules. I would like to know how to do this kind of tricks safely (accessing the bits of a `float` as if it were an `int`...) in compilers that apply these rules.

Comment: @comocomocomocomo You can safely type-pun with a union.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: No idea, target is ARM.

Comment: Ah, OK - then I have no further to add to this... And I'm not sure type punning is ever "safe" - you are in the hands of the compiler doing the right thing - someone said in another thread that "you can only have one active member in a union at any time", so type punning through union seems to be off as well - or I've misunderstood that comment.

Comment: I've just tried with gcc 4.6.3. If I type-pun with a union (no pointers involved at all) it works and I don't get any warnings. If I type-pun with pointers I get a warning, though it also works. (I'm using -Wall, of course). Thanks @Daniel Fischer

Comment: @MatsPetersson N1570, 6.5.2.3 (3), footnote 95: "If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation." So apart from trap representations, type punning via unions is safe per the standard [yes, footnotes are not normative, but it's crystal clear that it's intended to work].

Comment: @MSalters: I wrote a union-based version of the code of the question. Would you like me to add it somehow? I might add it to the question, or as an answer (though it's not a proper answer to your question).

Comment: @comocomocomocomo: Thanks but not needed. For me the real worry was about mathematical difficulties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newton's method produces a bias. The function whose zero is to be found,

```
f(y) = x - 1/y²
```

is concave, so - unless you start with an `y ≥ √(3/x)` - the Newton method only produces approximations `≤ 1/√x` (and strictly smaller, unless you start with the exact result) with exact arithmetic.

Floating point arithmetic occasionally produces too large approximations, but typically not in the first two iterations (since the initial guess usually isn't close enough).

So yes, there is a bias, and adding a small quantity generally improves the result. But not always. In the region around 1.25 or 0.85 for example, the results without the adjustment are better than with. In other regions, the adjustment yields one bit of additional precision, in yet others more.

In any case, the magic constant to add should be adjusted to the region from which `x` is most often taken for the best results.

Answer (score 2):

As this method is an approximation, the result will be overestimated some times and underestimated some others. You can find on [McEniry's paper](http://www.daxia.com/bibis/upload/406Fast_Inverse_Square_Root.pdf) some nice figures about how this error is distributed for different configurations, and the math behind them.

So, unless you have solid proofs that in your domain of application the result is clearly biased, I would prefer tuning the magic constant as suggested in [Lomont's document](http://www.lomont.org/Math/Papers/2003/InvSqrt.pdf) :-)

Comment: +1. Really like Lomont's analysis for the `0x5f375a86` constant.

Comment: Actually, with 0x5f3759df and 0x5f375a86 I get the exact same bias.

Comment: OK, I maintain what I said: if in your specific domain of application you know that bias exist, you can compensate it. Daniel Fisher answer is very clear about that ^_^