# Using a while loop to compute the approximation of a square root of a number

Tags: c, function, while-loop, square-root

I am trying to compute the square root of a number using function containing a while loop. Within the conditions of the while loop, I want to compare the absolute value of the ratio of the two values, the guessed square root and the number, to 1. However, whenever I run the program, I keep get an infinite loop outputting **1.414214**. Any help? Thanks.

```
// Function to calculate the absolute value of a number

#include <stdio.h>

float absoluteValue (float x)
{
    if ( x < 0 )
        x = -x;
    return (x);
}

// Function to compute the square root of a number

float   squareRoot (float x, const float epsilon)
{
    float       guess = 1.0;

    while ( absoluteValue ((guess * guess) / x) != epsilon ) {
        guess = ( (x / guess) + guess ) / 2.0;
        printf("%f\n", guess);
    }

        return guess;
}

int main (void)
{
    printf ("squareRoot (2.0) = %f\n", squareRoot (2.0, 1.0));
    printf ("squareRoot (144.0) = %f\n", squareRoot (144.0, 1.0));
    printf ("squareRoot (17.5) = %f\n", squareRoot (17.5, 1.0));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Testing floating point values for exact equality is almost always an error.

Comment: Your loop never ends because the loops condition is not satisfied. Find out why it is not satisfied.or when it should be satisfied.

Comment: Add this to your `while` loop if you want to see why: `printf("%f\n", absoluteValue((guess * guess)/x));`

Comment: Note: rather than use `%f`, recommend using `%e` to better see the relative precision of the values you are getting.

Comment: If you are kicking around square root functions, don't pass up a look at [**John Carmack's Unusual Fast Inverse Square Root**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349542/john-carmacks-unusual-fast-inverse-square-root-quake-iii). With a single iteration it is damn close, with 2 it is spot-on, with additional iterations, you exceed the precision of single-precision floating point. All thanks to the need for speed in *surface normal* calculations for 3D graphics.

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```
while ( absoluteValue ((guess * guess) / x) != epsilon ) {
```

To:

```
while ( absoluteValue ((guess * guess) / x - 1.0) > epsilon ) {
```

You want to keep refining your answer until it's within `epsilon` of the goal.  You need to subtract `1.0` from the ratio, to get the difference between what you're seeing and your goal, then you want to stop once the difference is within `epsilon`.  You don't want to keep trying if it's *smaller* than `epsilon`.

You will also want to use much smaller values for `epsilon`, e.g. `0.000001`

Comment: Or `fabs(guess*guess-x) > epsilon` if you want an absolute error tolerance (e.g. +/- 0.01 instead of +/- 1%).

Comment: @MooseBoys yes, that might be a better way to do it.  I was just trying to make the existing test do what was intended.