# Is it still worth using the Quake fast inverse square root algorithm nowadays on x86-64?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, x86-64, micro-optimization, sqrt

Specifically, this is the code I'm talking about:

```c
float InvSqrt(float x) {
  float xhalf = 0.5f*x;
  int i = *(int*)&x;        // warning: strict-aliasing UB, use memcpy instead
  i = 0x5f375a86- (i >> 1);
  x = *(float*)&i;          // same
  x = x*(1.5f-xhalf*x*x);
  return x;  
}
```

I forgot where I got this from but it's apparently better and more efficient or precise than the original Quake III algorithm (slightly different magic constant), but it's been more than 2 decades since this algorithm was created, and I just want to know if it's still worth using it in terms of performance, or if there's an instruction that implements it already in modern x86-64 CPUs.

Comment: it's from Quake: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Comment: In general modern compilers know what to do when you write this in a natural way and select appropriate compiler switches. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/PE3Mxd1Eh)

Comment: An expression like: `1.0f / sqrtf(x)` might require a flag like GCC's [`-fno-math-errno`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) - you can apply this option locally with [pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas). Even `sqrtss` followed by `divss` might be interleaved with other instructions to hide latencies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Origins:

See [John Carmack's Unusual Fast Inverse Square Root (Quake III)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349542/john-carmacks-unusual-fast-inverse-square-root-quake-iii)

---

#### Modern usefulness: none, obsoleted by SSE1 `rsqrtss`

Use `_mm_rsqrt_ps` or `ss` to get a very approximate reciprocal-sqrt for 4 floats in parallel, much faster than even a good compiler could do with this (using SSE2 integer shift/add instructions to keep the FP bit pattern in an XMM register, which is probably *not* how it would actually compile with the type-pun to integer.  Which is strict-aliasing UB in C or C++; use `memcpy` or C++20 `std::bit_cast`.)

https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rsqrtss documents the scalar version of the asm instruction, including the `|Relative Error| ≤ 1.5 ∗ 2−12` guarantee.  (i.e. about half the mantissa bits are correct.)  One Newton-Raphson iteration can refine it to within 1ulp of being correct, although still not the 0.5ulp you'd get from actual sqrt.  See [Fast vectorized rsqrt and reciprocal with SSE/AVX depending on precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555260/fast-vectorized-rsqrt-and-reciprocal-with-sse-avx-depending-on-precision))

`rsqrtps` performs only slightly slower than a `mulps` / `mulss` instruction on most CPUs, like 5 cycle latency, 1/clock throughput. (With a Newton iteration to refine it, more uops.) Latency various by microarchitecture, as low as 3 uops in Zen 3, but Intel runs it with about 5c latency since Conroe at least (https://uops.info/).

The integer shift / subtract from the magic number in the Quake InvSqrt similarly provides an even rougher initial-guess, and the rest (after type-punning the bit-pattern back to a `float` is a Newton Raphson iteration.

---

**Compilers will even use `rsqrtss` for you** when compiling `sqrt` with `-ffast-math`, depending on context and tuning options.  (e.g. modern clang compiling `1.0f/sqrtf(x)` with `-O3 -ffast-math -march=skylake` https://godbolt.org/z/fT86bKesb uses `vrsqrtss` and 3x vmulss plus an FMA.)  Non-reciprocal sqrt is usually not worth it, but rsqrt + refinement avoids a division as well as a sqrt.

---

Full-precision square root and division themselves are not as slow as they used to be, at least if you use them infrequently compared to mul/add/sub.  (e.g. if you can hide the latency, one sqrt every 12 or so other operations might cost about the same, still a single uop instead of multiple for rsqrt + Newton iteration.)  See [Floating point division vs floating point multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125033/floating-point-division-vs-floating-point-multiplication/45899202#45899202)
But sqrt and div do compete with each other for throughput so needing to divide by a square root is a nasty case.

So if you have a bad loop over an array that mostly just does sqrt, not mixed with other math operations, that's a use-case for `_mm_rsqrt_ps` (and a Newton iteration) as a higher throughput approximation than `_mm_sqrt_ps`

But if you *can* combine that pass with something else to increase computational intensity and get more work done overlapped with keeping the div/sqrt unit, often it's better to use a real sqrt instruction on its own, since that's still just 1 uop for the front-end to issue, and for the back-end to track and execute.  vs. a Newton iteration taking something like 5 uops if FMA is available for reciprocal square root, else more (also if non-reciprocal sqrt is needed).

With Skylake for example having 1 per 3 cycle `sqrtps xmm` throughput (128-bit vectors), it costs the same as a mul/add/sub/fma operation if you don't do more than one per 6 math operations.  (Throughput is worse for 256-bit YMM vectors, 6 cycles.)  A Newton iteration would cost more uops, so if uops for port 0/1 are the bottleneck, it's a win to just use sqrt directly.  (This is assuming that out-of-order exec can hide the latency, typically when each loop iteration is independent.)  This kind of situation is common if you're using a polynomial approximation as part of something like log or exp in a loop.

See also [Fast vectorized rsqrt and reciprocal with SSE/AVX depending on precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555260/fast-vectorized-rsqrt-and-reciprocal-with-sse-avx-depending-on-precision) re: performance on modern OoO exec CPUs.